# ASP.NET MVC 3 Unity DI - Resolve the parameter at runtime

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing ASP.NET MVC application using Unity DI framework. I am trying the scenario the web application to connect different database based URI segment. I tried several options and it is not successed.

I am registering all the objects in the unity container on Application Load event in Gloabl.asax file. It is working fine connecting with single database.

```
container.RegisterType<IContext, DbContext>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor("data source=.; Initial Catalog=catalog1; User ID=sa; Password=xxxxxx;"));
```

But I want to change the connection string dynamically based on URI parameter. Like  `http://www.domain.com/ABC`. If `ABC`, want to connect different database. How do i manually reslove the `DbContext` object at runtime before connecting to the database? or what is the best alternative option?

Answer (score 0):

You can name type registration and then resolve by name:

```
container.RegisterType<IContext, DbContext>("ABC", new PerRequestLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor("data source=.; Initial Catalog=catalog1; User ID=sa; Password=xxxxxx;"));

container.Resolve<IContext>("ABC")
```